# Can't run Python scripts with Miniconda in Geany

Tags: python, anaconda, geany

Im using Puppy Wary 5.5 and I've installed Miniconda in a folder at `/root/miniconda2`. I can run python scripts by pasting into the terminal window (urxvt)

Wary5.5 comes with Geany and appears to work ok. If I have a python script in Geany and I press F5, a new console window pops up with:

> ./geany_run_script.sh: line 5: python: command not found
>   (program exited with code: 127)
>   Press return to continue

and aborts on pressing return.

In a message window Geany reports that it failed to compile the script.

The bashrc file has the line

```
export PATH="/root/miniconda2/bin":$PATH
```

How do I get Geany to run a python script?

Comment: Did you check what is in /home/.config/geany/filedefs/filetypes.python ? Also it seems that your installation of miniconda was made under root. Try to run geany as root and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Geany is not using bashrc for finding your PYHOME when hitting F5 or similar. You got 3 ways solving it:

1. Put your setting into .profile or set it via your desktop environment
2. Adjust Build->Set Build Commands to your local path
3. Make usage of integrated VTE and bash inside there. Set Execute Programs in VTE on Edit->Preferences->Terminal

However, more general, you shouldn't run a graphical interface or coding direct as root user. It's in 99.8% of cases a bad idea.