# Geany can't import numpy from anaconda

Tags: python, geany

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. It came with python pre-installed. Today I installed Anaconda 2.7 and Geany as the IDE.

When i type "import numpy as np" in command line Python or IDLE it works fine. But when I execute the same in Geany it prompts "No module named numpy"

How can I fix this issue. 
Thanks much in advance.

Comment: What does `which python` return from each prompt?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply.

From the command promt;
/home/aluminium/anaconda2/bin/python

From Geany I used os.system("which python") and got this 
/usr/bin/python

Comment: Hi I got it working by putting the complete link in the execute path. Thanks so much for helping to find the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't run Python scripts with Miniconda in Geany](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36557575/cant-run-python-scripts-with-miniconda-in-geany)